# css animation call in js function does not work

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Can someone please help me with this?
function remove() is supposed to move the div away, when the form is submitted. However, this does not happen. What is wrong in the code?

The Gist of the code is [here](https://gist.github.com/maralexv/8901f2565f34e839848be6669af6d754).

snippets:

```js
function remove() {
    document.querySelector('.nickname').style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    alert('The Form was submitted');
};
```

```css
@keyframes up {
 from { 
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
 }
 to {
  opacity: 0;
  top: -110vh;
  hight: 0;
  line-height: 0;
 }
}
.nickname {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 opacity: 1;
 animation-name: up;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="nickname">
    <form onsubmit="remove()" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><h3>Hi there! Choose your nickname:</h3></legend>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nickname" size="60" autocomlete="off">
            <input type="text" name="useremail" placeholder="Email" size="60" autocomlete="off">
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Browsers often tend not to care about such stuff, when it is triggered by submitting a form - because that usually means that the current document will be replaced anyway. It might work if you trigger it on click of the submit button.

Comment: The animation DOES work, but it is not visualized due to the form submission. Your choices are to forget about the animation on the form submission - OR - submit the form data manually from inside the submit event handler.

Comment: Here is your JIST implemented to prevent the form submission so you can see the animation works as you designed. https://jsbin.com/raruhaholu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding your `remove` function to `onsubmit` event of a form.

All form `submit` events by default will reload the page. Hence your `js` will not work.

So what you need to do is :

```
function remove() {
    document.querySelector('.nickname').style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    alert('The Form was submitted');

    // run your ajax code to submit the form
    $.ajax({ blah blah});

    return false;       // do not submit the form

};
```

If you do this however, your form will not be submitted (but your javascript will work). So you can use ajax to post your form after you show the alert message

Comment: I am guessing they _want_ to submit the form data though …

Comment: ya i think it is outside the scope of the question:css animation call in js function does not work

Comment: but ya ofcourse you are correct, and can be handle with ajax or as you suggested use a click event

Comment: The JavaScript animation DOES work, but as you correctly point out, the page is reloaded prior to the effect of the animation actually being visualized.

Comment: I was planning to use Ajax to transfer form data